# Create a language switcher/swapper (not option select) with Vuei18n

Tags: i18next

I'm trying to use i18n to make a simple language changer for my site. I have the example from the documentation working at the moment. However, this example uses a dropdown to select the language which I don't want. Instead—since the site will only have two languages—I would like to detect the current language (for example, English) and display a link which reads "Visit our French language site". Upon clicking the link, the language would switch and the link would allow the user to return to the English version by clicking the link which now reads "Visit our English language site.

Here is my current language selector component (taken from the docs):

```
 <template>
  <div class="locale-changer">
    <select v-model="$i18n.locale">
      <option v-for="(lang, i) in langs" :key="`Lang${i}`" :value="lang">
        {{ lang }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'locale-changer',
  data () {
    return { 
      langs: ['en', 'fr']
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How can I do this? I've looked through the docs, but they don't seem very helpful. (To me, at least!) Could someone please help and give me some direction with this? It seems like it should be something very simple.